# How do I convert a string, represented as a list in MySQL database to a list in Django Template, so that I can iterate over it?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-templates

### **UPDATE:**

#### Additional information:

Python version: 3.4

OS: Windows

Django: 1.11.18

MySQL 8

#### models.py

`mailing_address = models.JSONField()`

#### views.py

# while inserting data

`data.locations = json.dumps(request.POST.getlist('locations'))`

`data.save()`

# while retrieving data

`my_requests_queryset = ListingModel.objects.filter(owner=request.user)`

`return render(request, 'home/home_dashboard_my_requests.html', {'my_requests_queryset': my_requests_queryset})`

I have stored a list of mailing addresses in the MySQL database like:

```
['1212 Los Angeles, CA', 'Nariman Point, Mumbai, India']
```

I expect to print each element of the list in my HTML template. Unfortunately, each character is being printed.

Now, when I try to iterate over the list, in the Django template, I get each character instead of each list element.

I have tried the Django library, **django-mysql** to implement native `JSONField`.

Tried building a list in Django template, using in-built template filters, `with`, `cycle`, `as list`, amongst others.

```
<div class="container">
    {% if my_requests_queryset and my_requests_queryset|length > 0 %}
    {% for req in my_requests_queryset %}
    <div class="row mb-1">
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <a href="#" class="card-link">
                <div class="card text-center">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        {{ req.title|title|truncatechars:36 }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">
                            {% for address in req.locations %}
                                {{ address }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

I expect to print each element in a list as:

```
1212 Los Angeles, CA
Nariman Point, Mumbai, India
```

Comment: Assign the JSON decoded value to locations not the string value.

Comment: Post the model that defines this field.

Comment: I have used `json.dumps()` to insert values into the database. @marekful

Comment: I have added an excerpt from my `models.py` and `views.py`. @DanielRoseman

Comment: You need to show the view code that is fetching that field and passing it to the template for display. I thought you said you were using a JsonField though?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm trying different combinations, JSONField and CharField. And I have updated my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, I'm using `json.dumps()` to insert the data into the database, which gets converted in to `String` type.

Hence, I need to do `json.loads()` before I could neatly display the data.

So, to solve this error, I have directly inserted the values into the database, like

`locations = request.POST.getlist('locations')`

instead of

`locations = json.dumps(request.POST.getlist('locations'))`